# How do I check if an email address is associated with a Paypal account?

Tags: api, paypal

Is there an easy way (API) to find out if a user has a Paypal account or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - check out the GetVerifiedStatus Method in the new PayPal Adaptive Accounts API (https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_accounts).

Obviously this API access is not allowed for everyone unless there is a valid use case. So please contact the PayPal Technical Support to see if your use case qualifies for this API.