# Is a valid paypal email address or not (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal adaptive payments and i need to verify email address from paypal api given by the store/seller, so that the payment can be directly given to store by customers.

i want to check that if store's given email is a valid paypal email address and he/she has signed up for paypal or not.

tell me if PayPal supports and allows Application to access or not.

and also give me sample code please in php

Comment: I think those mailed are signed with DKIM, just check that signatures

Comment: found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640475/how-do-i-check-if-an-email-address-is-associated-with-a-paypal-account

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes PayPal supports this feature via the use of "GetVerifiedStatus" API where you have to input the email address , first name and the last name as the required parameter and it will return the response like below :

```
Response:
responseEnvelope.timestamp: 2014-10-01T01%3A17%3A10.081-07%3A00
responseEnvelope.ack: Success
responseEnvelope.correlationId: ce5a28138ca78
responseEnvelope.build: 13068405
accountStatus: VERIFIED
userInfo.emailAddress: XXXXXXX
userInfo.accountType: BUSINESS
userInfo.accountId: XXXXXXXX
userInfo.name.salutation: 
userInfo.name.firstName: Eshan+Business+Test
userInfo.name.middleName: 
userInfo.name.lastName: Account
userInfo.name.suffix: 
userInfo.businessName: Eshan+New+Business+Name
```

You can use the below php code for this :

```
<?php

  $url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus");  //set PayPal Endpoint to sandbox
//$url = trim("https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus");         //set PayPal Endpoint to Live 

$API_UserName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";                                //PayPal Test API Credentials, Replace it with live if in live mode
$API_Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$API_Signature = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";                                       //Default App ID for Sandbox, replace it with live id if in live mode   
$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

//Create request payload 
$bodyparams = array (   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                        "emailAddress" =>"put email address to check ",
                        "firstName" =>"XXXXX",
                        "lastName" =>"XXXXXX",
                        "matchCriteria" => "NAME"
                    );

// convert payload array into url encoded query string
$body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));

try
{
    //create request and add headers
    $params = array("http" => array( 
                                    "method" => "POST",
                                    "content" => $body_data,
                                    "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:     " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                                                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:  " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                                                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:   " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                                                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:      " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                                                "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                                                "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:" . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
                                    ));


     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);  //create stream context
     $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);   //open the stream and send request
     $response = stream_get_contents($fp);   //get response

    //check to see if stream is open
     if ($response === false) 
     {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

     fclose($fp);    //close the stream

    //parse the ap key from the response

    $keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal)
    {
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
            $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

//print the request to screen for testing purposes
echo "Header info:" . "<br>";
print_r($params['http']['header']);
echo "<br><br>" . "Request Info:" . "<br>";
print_r(urldecode($params['http']['content']));
echo "<br><br>" . "Response:" . "<br>";

//print the response to screen for testing purposes
    If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") 
    {

         foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value)
         {
          echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
         }
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value)
        {
        echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
        }       
    }

 }

catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
}

echo "<br>";  
?>
```

Comment: @eshan i am getting this error
 stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @kunal will you help me to understand this example?

Comment: @gourav still i am not able to understand this example provided by Eshan

Comment: @kunal But I will understand the example this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461347/9703809. I will explain you if you want. I tell you each and every thing about it

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Paypay Adaptive Accounts](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptiveAccounts) and look for GetVerifiedStatus

There is also an SDK for it https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php

Comment: after istalling sdk it give errors. can't we just use curl so that avoid using classes of paypal? any sample will help thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    $email_pay=json_decode($this->config->item('paypal_payment')); 
    $paypal_email=$email_pay->email;
    $paypal_username=$email_pay->username;
    $paypal_password=$email_pay->password;
    $paypal_appid=$email_pay->appid;
    $paypal_signature=$email_pay->signature;
    $mode=$email_pay->mode;
    if($mode==0)
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";
    }
    else
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";
    }

    $ret['error_new']='';   
    $payLoad["emailAddress"]=$_POST['paypal_email'];
    $payLoad["matchCriteria"]="NONE";       $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
        'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
        'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: '. $paypal_username,
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: '. $paypal_password,
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: '. $paypal_signature,
        'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: '. $paypal_appid
    ));  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payLoad));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response, 1); 
    if(empty($response['error'])){
        //valid account
    }
    else{
        $ret['error_new']='Please enter valid paypal email id.';    
    }

    }       
    else
    {           
        $ret['status']=0;
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

**//  For Live Account**

$url = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";

**// For Sandbox**

$url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";

```
    $payLoadData = [
        'emailAddress' => 'sb-sfdkg15DS225491@personal.example.com',
        'matchCriteria' => 'NONE',
    ];

    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT' => env('PAYPAL_REQUEST_DATA_FORMAT'),
        'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => env('PAYPAL_RESPONSE_DATA_FORMAT'),
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' => env('PAYPAL_SECURITY_USERID'),
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' => env('PAYPAL_SECURITY_PASSWORD'),
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' => env('PAYPAL_SECURITY_SIGNATURE'),
        'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_APP_ID'),
    ])->post($url, $payLoadData);

    $returnBackResponse  = json_decode($response);

   if (Arr::exists($response, 'accountStatus')) {
        if ($returnBackResponse->accountStatus == 'VERIFIED') {
            dd($returnBackResponse);
        } else {
            dd($returnBackResponse->error[0]->message);
        }
    } else {
        dd($returnBackResponse->error[0]->message);
    }
```

**SUCCESS RESPONSE**

[PAYPAL EMAIL ACCOUNT VERFICATION SUCCESS REPONSE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJhkv.png)