# How to check paypal email is valid or not?

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting stuck on this i want to check that paypal email id is verified ,exists or not. I am using laravel 5.2 and i have find the code from this answer from stackoverflow:

[Is a valid paypal email address or not (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134515/is-a-valid-paypal-email-address-or-not-php?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But i am getting this error:-

> stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given

I don't know how the answer is accepted please help me. How to reslove this issue. I want to check paypal email is verified or not

Here is my php code

```
$url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus");  //set PayPal Endpoint to sandbox
$API_UserName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$API_Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$API_Signature = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T"; 
$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

$bodyparams = array ("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                    "emailAddress" =>"myemail@gmail.com",
                    "firstName" =>"Kunal",
                    "lastName" =>"Mahajan",
                    "matchCriteria" => "NAME"
                );

$body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));

try{
    $params = array("http" => array( 
                "method" => "POST",
                "content" => $body_data,
                "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:     " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:  " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:   " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:      " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:" . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
        ));

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);  //create stream context
    $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);   //open the stream and send request
    $response = stream_get_contents($fp);   //get response

    if ($response === false){
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
    }

    fclose($fp);    //close the stream

    //parse the ap key from the response

    $keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
        $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

    echo "Header info:" . "<br>";
    print_r($params['http']['header']);
    echo "<br><br>" . "Request Info:" . "<br>";
    print_r(urldecode($params['http']['content']));
    echo "<br><br>" . "Response:" . "<br>";
    if ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success"){
        foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value) {
            echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
            echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
        }       
    }

}catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
}
```

Comment: you should post your php code in order to let us understand where the mistake is

Comment: @IaconisSimone i have tried same code but only thing i have change the api username,signature and password ... rest all are same

Comment: @IaconisSimone i have add my code see

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

instead of

```
$fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);   //open the stream and send request
    $response = stream_get_contents($fp);   //get response
```

and change this:

```
$params = array("http" => array( 
                "method" => "POST",
                "content" => $body_data,
                "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:     " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:  " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:   " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:      " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:" . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
        ));
```

to this:

```
$params = array("http" => array( 
                "method" => "POST",
                "content" => $body_data,
                "header" =>
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURIY-USERID:     " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:  " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:   " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:      " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:" . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" .
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
));
```

Comment: Are you running your code on a proxy? you can check here: http://amibehindaproxy.com/

Comment: yes i am in behind the proxy but i have tried in some another internet connection i.e is not in proxy but it is also not working

Comment: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: add Content-type: to the request header as in the answer

Comment: file_get_contents(https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Comment: according to this questions: stackoverflow.com/questions/17858746/… it means that the email, name and surname doesen't correspond to any paypal account